# Easier way to extract a substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a substring matching a given pattern from a string in Javascript.
Example:

```
var classProp = 'active category_games',
    match = classProp.match(/category_[a-z]+\b/),
    category;
if(match !== null && match.length > 0){
  category = match[0];
}
```

Is there an easier way to acheive this? A one-liner, preferably?

Comment: This golfing can be a fun exercise, but given the answers so far (an extra array instantiation, a try/catch clause) I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should there be a `\b` before category?
You could shorten it by supplying an empty array if the match fails;

```
 category = (classProp.match(/category_[a-z]+\b/) || [""])[0];
```

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it be more correct to skip the \b in the end, as I wouldn't want the \b included in the match, although it won't be a problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more equivalent to the OP to write `(… || [null])`?

Comment: Quite possibly, I just used "" as its the "empty" implementation of a valid category

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is already very close to a one-liner.  You could simplify your "if" block to the following:

```
if(match){
  category = match[0];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I wish I wouldn't have to use the match variable. I always end up naming it stupidly, like "tmp" or something :(

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
try { var category = 'active category_games'.match(/category_[a-z]+\b/).pop(); } catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Isn't there are few issues with instanciating variables inside a try/catch-block? I thought it could cause a memory leak in older IE versions.

Comment: @Jørgen Personally I think old IE is not worth worrying about, but it's easily overcome by adding a `finally { category = null }` after the try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one-liner:

```
var category = (classProp.match(/category_[a-z]+\b/) || "")[0] || undefined;
```

But I would advise you to use @ziesemer's answer.